# How to store the view output in memcache in django. When I am storing the data in cache it storing None

Tags: django, caching, django-views, memcached

This is My View code, on POST request, I will pass some start_date and end_date to CumulativeMain method, after some calculation it returns the dataframe. This dataframe, I want to store into the cache. But it is storing the None values.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
      cache_key = 'portfolio_returns'       # this key stores prtfolio returns data 
      cache_time = 86400                    # time in seconds for cache to be valid
      cumulative_return = cache.get(cache_key)
      if not cumulative_return:
           cumulative_return= CumulativeMain(start_date,current_date) #it returns dataframe
           cache.set(cache_key, cumulative_return, cache_time)
      print(cache.get(cache_key))           # printing None instead of data
```